# Cypress how to set the date without affecting intervals

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

I am trying to set the time of the browser so I can do some time-based validation. Unfortunately when I set the time as below intervals do not trigger. I can manually make the intervals fire by ticking. Is there a way to allow the time ticking to continue after setting the date?

  `const dateToSet = new Date(date).getTime()
  cy.clock(dateToSet, ["Date"])`

Answer (score 16):

Just overwrite `Date` alone:

```
cy.clock(Date.UTC(2020, 6, 23), ['Date']);
```

Comment: This saved me big time.

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the cypress documentation, you can then use `cy.tick()` to simulate time.

I think that cypress assumes you want to control time yourself when you invoke the clock, sounds like reasonable behaviour to me.

> cy.clock() yields a clock object with the following methods:
>
> clock.tick(milliseconds)
>
> Move the clock the specified number of milliseconds. Any timers within
>   the affected range of time will be called.
>
> clock.restore()
>
> Restore all overridden native functions. This is automatically called
>   between tests, so should not generally be needed.
>
> You can also access the clock object via this.clock in a .then()
>   callback.

Read more at https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/clock.html#Syntax

Comment: This simply restates exactly what the OP is already doing.